# How can I continuously check the hour within a while loop?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

This is my first post and first project in Python. I'm trying to control a hardware sensor through a number of conditions:

1. If the sensor senses movement, send e-mail and sleep
2. elif the time range is not between work hours, then sleep until 9am
3. else sleep for half a second and wait for sensor

So far the first condition and the last condition work. That is, if there is no movement, repeat sleep(0.5) until the sensor activates.

**Issue:** I'm having trouble with the middle portion where the time is not between 9-5. If I run the code before 9 or after 5, it sleeps until 9am arrives as intended, but if the code is already running between 9-5 (waiting for movement), the middle condition never triggers. It gets stuck on sleep(0.5).

I'm not that experienced but I have a vague idea that a second process should help keep track of time. Any suggestions? Here is the code.

```
def pir_init():
    while True:
        m = datetime.datetime.now().time().minute   #loop through for current time
        h = datetime.datetime.now().time().hour     
        if h < 9:                                           
            print("Sleeping...")
            time_sleep = (9 - h) * 3600
            time.sleep(time_sleep)
        elif h > 16:
            print("Sleeping...")
            time_sleep = ((24 - h) + 9) * 3600
            time.sleep(time_sleep)
        elif io.input(pir_pin):
            print("PIR ALARM")
            send_gmail()   
            time.sleep(10)      #cooldown to prevent email spew
        else:
            print "Waiting..."
            time.sleep(0.5)     #sleep and wait for movement
            print m
    print "Loop End"


# main
if time_elements[0] > '0' and time_elements[0] < '6':  #Weekdays
    if get_hour > 8 and get_hour < 17:             #Hour Range
        pir_init()
    elif get_hour > 16:
        print("Initialization at 9am...")
        time_sleep = ((24 - get_hour) + 9) * 3600
        time.sleep(time_sleep)
        pir_init()              #initiate sensor
    elif get_hour < 9:
        print("Initialization at 9am...")
        time_sleep = (9 - get_hour) * 3600
        time.sleep(time_sleep)
        pir_init()
else:
    #to be completed
    print time_elements[0]
    print "bad weekday"
```

Comment: You've got a lot of indentation issues with your code sample, I only point it out because you said that this is your first Python project, so I wanted to give you a chance to clean up your formatting before people offer help on the actual logic

Comment: Also you can get the current hour as an int by adding `from datetime import datetime` to the top and `datetime.now().time().hour`

Comment: I'm assuming this is based on this device and code? http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-12-sensing-movement/software

Comment: Yes, it is based on that motion detector example. I didn't know you could get the hour as an int so i'll have to adjust my code accordingly, Thanks. 

@siluatyThis was my solution for retrieving the hour:
       `now = datetime.datetime.now()
       strtime = now.strftime("%w %H %M") 
       time_elements = strtime.split()                                
       time_sleep = int((24 - int(time_elements[1])) + 9) * 3600`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the time_elements inside your while loop, so that the program uses the current time in the condition to test if it shall sleep until 9a.m. Otherwise, if you don't update the time_elements inside that while loop, if the program didn't enter in that condition in the first time, it will never enter.

That explains the behavior you are noticing; in fact, your definition of time_elements isn't shown here...

Comment: That sounds like the correct way to accomplish this. Am I correct in understanding that the time should be passed in to the function pir_init(current_time)?

Comment: No, you shouldn't pass it as an argument, because you have to get the current time inside the loop and update it in each iteration. You can do that importing datetime:
 import datetime
 and then inside the loop:
 date = datetime.datetime.now()
 ... elif date.hour<9 or date.hour>17:
     time.sleep(time_sleep)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The reason I wanted the time to be passed in and updated was because when the program is initially launched, it should either sleep or activate the sensor in the same way the while loop does. I suppose I'll have to reuse the same time formulas inside and outside the loop.